# 400 Bad Request - Trying to stream webcam using readfile() on external URL

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to stream an ipcamera through PHP using the following code;

```
<?
# Stop apache timing out
set_time_limit(0);

# Set the correct header
header('Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=ipcamera');

# Read the images
readfile('http://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/videostream.cgi');
?>
```

This script works just fine on my localhost running apache and php, however on my web server (tested on 2 servers), I receive a 400 Bad Request error. I was previously receiving a 'connection refused' error, but this was resolved by my host forwarding the correct port.

Is 400 not something like incorrect syntax? Could this be because i have the "[USER]:[PASSWORD]@" in the url? If so, is there another way I can authenticate  before running readfile?

I have run the following cases to determine the response code;

```
readfile('http://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/NONEXISTINGFILE.cgi');
// Returns 400 Bad Request (Should be 404)

readfile('http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/NONEXISTINGFILE.cgi');
// Returns 404 Not Found (Correct Response)

readfile('http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/videostream.cgi');
// Returns 401 Unauthorized (Correct Response)

readfile('http://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/videostream.cgi');
// Returns 400 Bad Request (Incorrect - Should be .. 200(?) OK)

readfile('http://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/FILETHATDOESEXIST.jpg');
// Returns 400 Bad Request (Should be 200(?) OK)

readfile('http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/FILETHATDOESEXIST.jpg');
// Returns 200(?) OK (Correct Response)
```

If someone is able to give me the curl equivalent of this script, perhaps this is the solution. The Bounty still stands to anyone who can solve this for me :)

Regards,

Comment: **400** The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.

Comment: I do understand the error, just not how to stop it :P

Comment: What happens if you try to access anything other than videostream.cgi? Do you get normal 404 errors for non existing files? Do normal downloadable files work?

Comment: That's a good point. I tried a file that doesn't exist and I still got the 400 error. However, when removing the [user]:[password]@  and requesting the file that doesn't exist, I do get a correct 404. If I do a request without the authentication details to the videostream.cgi, I get a 401 not authenticated error (Which is correct). This makes me assume it's something to do with the authenticating. I have edited my post to include some test cases.

Comment: Do you have any illegal characters in your password or username? Any of these: ?,&,@,:, %?

Comment: Absolutely not, for testing purposes the username and password are 100% lowercase characters. But obviously there's the colon and @ symbol in the request url, perhaps the readfile sends the "user:password@" urlencoded or something? - Note the existing "image" file, works without authentication, but doesn't work with the authentication details.

Comment: No i don't think so... Although it is definitely the username and password that causes this error.. Is there a proxy between the server and the camera? Or just a NAT firewall? And: Do you have SSH access to the server? If so, can you get any of the existing files using wget?

Comment: As far as I know there's just a NAT firewall on the standard router that the camera connects to, and I believe there's a DMZ on the camera's IP. It would make sense that perhaps my web servers have something else though, if it works from my localhost web server perfectly (no 400 headers), and not from them.

Comment: And the wget? Does that work?

Comment: I've not tried wget as I don't have access to the exec() function on my server so don't think it would work at all.

Comment: I think you should try to look at raw HTTP request that your PHP readfile() generates (there are lot's of ways to do it). If you find some problems with it - you can generate custom headers with curl(), PHP's sockets, etc. If nothing helps you can try to create a proxy application on some server(maby ipcamera's?) that will connect to your ipcamera's server with that authentification method and stream content, while using different authentification method itself.

Comment: What are the PHP versions on the servers you've tested this, including localhost? You might just use a feature that is not available in all PHP versions. And can you provide the URI of the stream that is live? That would be useful to get an own impression on your issue.

Comment: Can it be the problem? http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php#78703

Comment: @Karolis Perhaps, but how do I tell if it's Digest or Basic? I'm pretty sure it's just Basic.

Comment: @Joel Please use a tool like wireshark or tcpdump and grab the traffic going across. This will give you a direct route to resolution.

Answer (score 2):

For curl, try something like:

```
<?php

# Stop apache timing out
set_time_limit(0);

# Set the correct header
header('Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=ipcamera');

# Read the images
$ch = curl_init('http://[IPADDRESS]:[PORT]/videostream.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[USER]:[PASSWORD]');
curl_exec($ch);
```

If you want to continue to use readfile(), you *could* use stream_context_create() to construct a stream context for readfile. See [this documentation on php.net](http://php.net/context.http) to see how that could be done - specifically, you will want to create an HTTP stream context that passes an Authentication header.

Comment: That really does work quite well. I only wanted to avoid curl due to the supposed simplicity of readfile, and because I've seen a lot of people criticise curl lately. Thank you! :) P.S. I did look at the stream_context_create stuff, but seems like a lot more overhead than just doing this.

Comment: I feel where readfile() *truly* excels is in local filesystem stuff. If your HTTP request were truly simple, it could work there as well, but in this case, your need goes a bit beyond the simple, so you're going to have to use a more flexible approach. Either way, glad to help. :)

Comment: Could you possibly give me advice/example on how to output this to an image file. The problem is that the webcam only allows a certain number of connections to it, and everytime someone views the image at the moment, obviously the php creates a new connection to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simply check your `[USER]` and `[PASSWORD]` ... make sure it does not contains `:, /, @` ...

if there is escape it with `\`

Comment: Thanks, as per the comments on the first post, the username and password are all 100% lowercase alphanumeric characters.

Comment: ok, my bad, it should return 401 error if the username/password contains illegal characters instead of error 400

Answer (score 0):

You might have something set in your PHP.INI on the production server that is disabling readfile's ability to load external URLs.

I'm specifically thinking about **allow_url_fopen** which may be set to FALSE, though it may be something else.

You can also check you web server's error log for clues.  PHP will usually emit a specific warning.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is ON. If it were not, I'd be receiving php errors rather than correct 404s e.t.c.